# MonoTouch/Objective-C - Detect How Much of a UIImageView is Currently Visible

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView as a subview of a UIScrollView, the image view is filled using a CGBitmapContext which is drawn to using a DrawTileAtIndex method.

In order to increase performance, I would only like to draw those tiles that are visible, is there any way I can detect how much of my UIImageView is currently visible to the user?  I.E What area, pixels etc  If so, how do I detect this in order to draw the correct tiles?

- CATiledLayer is not an option.

Thanks in advance,

Jack

Comment: I'm a little confused here since I would imagine you'd use a UIView subclass to display your image (and thus gain control over drawRect:) instead of stuffing the image in a UIImageView.

Comment: I see what you mean, could you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an image that is larger than can be viewed at any one time, then create a UIView subclass with the image as a property. When you are sent drawRect:, then you can use the passed in rect to test your tiles against, and only those tiles that overlap that rect need to be drawn.

You can use the 'CGRectIntersectsRect' function to do the test.